# commentsthreaded.count property not available in excel 365 vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to adjust some workbook audit code for the new threaded comments. Basically the code would cycle through all workbook comments (notes) and consolidate them into a new sheet at the end of the workbook.

With what is now notes, I use the following (noting cmt1 is declared as a comment object and wsSource is a worksheet object)

```
For Each cmt1 In wsSource.Comments
            'Collect comment data for testing/pasting
            strSheetname = wsSource.Name
            strCmt = cmt1.Text
            strCellref = cmt1.Parent.Address
            strContent = cmt1.Parent.Formula
etc.
```

Now with threaded comments, the same type of approach didn't work. I am trying to do a numerical loop using a counter and having code like the below:

```
For x = 1 to wsSource.commentsthreaded.count
```

However the count property doesn't work. According to the nmicrosoft website, it should be one of the 4 available properties.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.commentsthreaded

Does anyone else have this issue? Any way to fix it?

Comment: The class looks like any other object collection class, which is always best iterated with a `For Each` loop. Not saying `Count` should be expected to fail, but why does the index matter? Without a `For...Next` loop you don't need to care about the `Count`...

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean, specifically? Are you getting any particular error? Does `wsSource` have a `CommentsThreaded` property? What build/version are you  running?

Comment: I'm running version 1904 build 11601.20178

Comment: I tried the exact same code I use to extract normal comments (notes) for the threaded comments, but get error 1004. It says method 'commentsthreaded' of worksheet object failed

Comment: I would prefer to use the For Each loop instead of the count, but since it was failing I tried a different way using the count property since the microsoft help for threadedcomments seemed to suggest it was a viable property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved - it looks like the problem was the Excel version. I was running 1904 and it now works since updating to 1906.